# POSTGRES_DB and POSTGRES_USER don't work in Docker run

Tags: postgresql, docker

So I am running the following command:

```
docker run --name psql-instance -d -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_DB=mydb -e POSTGRES_USER=root -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass postgres
```

This creates the container.

However when I run:

```
docker exec -it psql-instance psql -U root
```

I get the following error:

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  database "root" does not exist
```

I've seen many similar questions and they all say its `docker-compose` causing the error for them and that `docker run` works fine but for me, `docker run` doesn't work.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell `psql` to connect to the `mydb` database like this

```
docker exec -it psql-instance psql -U root mydb
```